# set delegate and datasource of uitableview programmatically in Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, delegates, datasource

I would like to set the `delegate` and `datasource` for 'tableView`in`ViewController.swift` file.

I wrote this code in my viewDidLoad function, but it's not working.

Code:

```
    tableView.delegate?.self
    tableView.dataSource?.self
```

I'm working with CoreData and my Entity is named "Note".

Hope someone can help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to set the delegate and data source is:

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still get this error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
`

Comment: You have provided no info in your question about what error you have. Is that error the same before and after the proposed change? You should provide more details, such as where the error happens, some relevant code etc. And I suggest you to add that in a separate section of your question (do not replace the original)

Comment: Ok. I posted a question about this error in the past, where I also provided more details about the error, where the error happended ... This is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27001729/coredata-error-reloaddata-in-swift I Hope this details are useful.

Answer (score -3):

Do this, it will work

```
tableView.delegate      =   self
tableView.dataSource    =   self
```

Comment: this doesn't differ in any way to the answer provided b Antonio 3 month ago