# cells in collection view are not visible if calling from another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Here is the code of ProductViewController

```
import UIKit

class ProductViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource,   UICollectionViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!

let array:[String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let itemSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/3 - 2

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemSize, height: itemSize)

    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 2
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 2

    myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//Number of views
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

//Populate view
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! myCell
    cell.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row] + ".JPG")
    return cell
}

}
```

But I am calling this ProductViewController from button in ViewController code is here

```
 @IBAction func view(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let LogInVController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProductViewController") as! ProductViewController
    self.present(LogInVController, animated: true)

}
```

If I am making a standalone application with ProductViewController code as in ViewController , I am able to see the content cells of collectionview.
But If I am calling ProductViewController from Button of ViewController cells are not visible.
Please help as I am new in iOS
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When go to CollecetionView in display cells without content or didn't display any cell ?

Comment: @Hosny without content & cells are also not there,it loads till viewdidload mycollectionview but no cell or content after that. Don't know why this strange issue. Standalone working without button pressing, as I mentioned.

Comment: is numberOfsection method call?

Comment: @Hosny No these methods are not getting called

Comment: you are sure you connected delegate and dataSource of collection view ?

Comment: @Hosny Thanks you saved my day man

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes Thanks @Hosny I have not connected datasource and delegate,
that's why this problem I faced.
As I am new so it happened from next time ,I will cross check.
Thanks a lot man.

And here's how to connect them I found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33694415/how-to-connect-datasource-and-delegate-with-code-ios-swift)